# Creating records using ForeignKey in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am having four models `auth_user`, `B`, `C`, and `D`. `auth_user` is the parent model for `B`, `C`, and `D`. How can I create a serializer for `auth_user` when a POST request comes, it can  insert `auth_user` and then it creates a record in `B`, `C`, and `D` serially. If any exception occurs at any point all the transactions should be rolled back. Can I achieve this using DRF?

my models:

```
class B(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(auth_user)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 10) 

class C(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(auth_user)
    owner = model.ForeignKey(auth_user) ## existing user ID
    phone = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

class D(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    user = models.ForeignKey(auth_user)
```

I am having a ajax call which posts

```
{'owner_id':1,'name':xxx,'phone':899,'key':123}
```

to an API url which should create new user in `auth_user` table and use that `user_id` to make entry in model `B`, `C`, and `D`. If it fails at any point it should rollback all the transaction in `auth_user`, `B`, `C`, and `D`.

How can I write the serializer and views for this in Django REST Framework.

Comment: I can say that yes, this is possible using DRF.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? It's easier for us to work from an example that you provide and help you fix any issues you have come across.

Comment: @KevinBrown I am using serializers.RelatedField to get the data and I can able to view corresponding tables object but am not sure whether I can create resource in that way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`CreateAPIView`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createapiview) with your `B` model and a custom form, which has all the fields `B` needs and all the fields `User` needs. Then when you override the `create` function in your view to first create a `User` and then a `B`.

As for transactions stuff, [the django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/transactions/) explain it all.